# How to iterate through an excel sheet based on whether the cell value contains a certain character

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to write a script that will delete rows based on whether or not the row's corresponding cell value in the first column contains a specific character, in this case a '#'.

I have tried writing the following function that would hopefully iterate through the sheet and return a new sheet with the deleted rows. LabSample is the sheet that I am working in.

```
def remove_headers():
    for rowNum in range(2, LabSample.max_row):
        sys_sample_code = LabSample.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value
        if '#' not in sys_sample_code:
            continue
        else:
            LabSample.delete_rows(rowNum, 1)
    return LabSample

for row in LabSample.rows:
    print(row[0].value)
```

I currently am not getting any error messages, but the output I am getting is unchanged from the input. It appears that no rows have been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting sys_sample_code as a str()

```
#...
sys_sample_code = LabSample.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value
        if '#' not in str(sys_sample_code): # SEE EDIT HERE
        # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do this through importing the table in numpy and then index the rows which contain the '#', and finally use np.delete to remove the rows before pushing it back to where it came.

Here's a short example which kinda demonstrates what I'm talking about. just replace the starting array 'x' with your data array and analyze along the column you're interested in.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(
        [1,2,5,'a','#test1', 'b', 7, '#test2', 9]
         )

index = {count: pos for count, pos in enumerate(x) if '#' in pos[:]}

x = np.delete(x, list(index.keys()))


In [17]: x
Out[17]: array(['1', '2', '5', 'a', 'b', '7', '9'], dtype='<U11')
```

Comment: If you share your data, or an example data file, we could be more specific with the syntax, but for now this general example should point you in the right direction.